# How to center items of a recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I need to center elements in each row so they will be like in this mockup.
I've been searching if there is any layout that works that way without look.
items are centered in their rows.

[image: mockup]

This is how it looks now in my code.[image]

Comment: It sounds pretty similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34206078/center-a-cardview-in-a-recyclerview-with-only-one-element

Comment: Has This problem been solved ?

Comment: you might just need to make a custom layoutManager since the GridLayoutManager does not help with this. I did post an answer but I'm not sure if its exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: How to make this layout?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Achieved with:

```
recyclerView.adapter = MyAdapter()
val layoutManager = FlexboxLayoutManager(context).apply {
    justifyContent = JustifyContent.CENTER
    alignItems = AlignItems.CENTER
    flexDirection = FlexDirection.ROW 
    flexWrap = FlexWrap.WRAP
}
recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
```

You need to add [FlexboxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) to your gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0'
```

[image]

Answer (score 87):

Make recyclerview `width` to `wrap_content` and its container's `layout_gravity` to `center_horizontal`

```
 <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
           android:id="@+id/recycrer_view"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:paddingLeft="16dp"
           android:paddingRight="16dp" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This will prevent scrolling the RecyclerView from the sides.

Answer (score 41):

Take `LinearLayout` in your `RecyclerView`'s item row layout then give `android:layout_gravity="center"` to `LinearLayout`.

For each row of images you have to take different `LinearLayout`.

Here is example code:

```
 <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/image1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image2"
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/image2" />

           <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image3"
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/image3" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I had to modify the RecyclerView layout_width="wrap_content" rather than match_parent as well

Comment: @jemkuan That will disable scrolling when the user swipes on the edge or outer region of the parent, as the width of the RecyclerView will be less than the width of the parent.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the recycler view will register a click event when user will touch outside of the image views.

Answer (score 8):

I am assuming that you are using a `LinearLayoutManager` with a `RecyclerView` for a `ListView`-style effect. In that case, use a `horizontal` `LinearLayout` for each row, with `android:gravity="center"` to center its contents.

Comment: Actually i'm using gridlayout but let me try that.

Comment: @cgomezmendez: I presume that there would be some way to do that via `GridLayoutManager`, or else via a custom `RecyclerView.LayoutManager`. I do not see, at a quick glance, how to do it with `GridLayoutManager`.

Comment: did you fixed the problem?

Comment: For my project using recycler view with grid layout, where items are centered using gravity attribute works fine.

Comment: this did not help :(

Answer (score 6):

Use `FlexboxLayout` from `com.google.android:flexbox` library. Note the `flexwrap` and `justifyContent` property values. Then, set `layout_wrapBefore = true` on the view that you want to wrap the line of items before.

```
    <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:flexWrap="wrap"
        app:justifyContent="center">

        <View ... />

        <View app:layout_wrapBefore="true" ... />

        <View ... />

    </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

Comment: I would like to add this is a very clean way to do this. Specially you can use the library as a `layoutManager` for `recyclerview`. All you have to do is set up the layout manager with direction and alignment requirements. No need to make a two dimensional recyclerview as mentioned by third top answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context,6)` and override `setSpanSizeLookup`.

Example:

```
int totalSize=list.size();
gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
                    @Override
                    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                        int span;
                        span = totalSize % 3;
                        if (totalSize < 3) {
                            return 6;
                        } else if (span == 0 || (position <= ((totalSize - 1) - span))) {
                            return 2;
                        } else if (span == 1) {
                            return 6;
                        } else {
                            return 3;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

This will work if you want to display 3 items in a row and remaining in the center of the grid.

Change the grid layout manager span counts accordingly your requirement.

Answer (score 4):

you can use the new layoutManager from google [FlexLayoutManager](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)
it will gives you a lot of control and flexibility over the recyclerView items

Answer (score 3):

you can add some layouts dynamically, for example:

- adapter object can be a horizontal LinearLayout

1- create a LinearLayout in java code and customize it (gravity,...)

2- add some icons to linearLayout

3- add linearLayout to your adapter

4- repeat 1,2,3

---

```
    // : declare new horizontal linearLayout
    ImageView myIcons[nomOfIcons];
    // : add all icons to myIcons
    for(int i=1; i<=nomOfIcons; i++){
        linearLayout.addView(myIcons[i - 1]);
        if(i%numOfIconsInOneHorizontalLinearLayout==0) {
            results.add(linearLayout); // add linearLayout to adapter dataSet
            // : declare new horizontal linearLayout
        }
    }
    if(n%numOfIconsInOneHorizontalLinearLayout!=0) // add last linearLayout if not added in the loop
        results.add(linearLayout);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // update adapter
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Trust me, this gonna work.
In your main xml file where you've put the recycler view, copy my code.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I think we need to write our own custom view for it because Android has not supported this feature as we expected yet.

It is the Sample I made in case someone needs it:
https://github.com/mttdat/utils

*(Try the CenterGridActivity.kt by adjusting Manifest file to start this activity as default)*

Answer (score 1):

In case you need the Java Version of AskQ's reply:

```
    // Set layout manager to position the items
    FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.CENTER);
    layoutManager.setAlignItems(AlignItems.CENTER);
    layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
    layoutManager.setFlexWrap(FlexWrap.WRAP);
    adapter.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```